# pytest-reportportal raises test names key errors

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, reportportal

So I m using pytest-reportportal library to generate rp launch

But for some reason (only happens on ubuntu server, launched via github actions wf)
The errors are as follows

```
collected 403 items / 325 deselected / 78 selected
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 272, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 326, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 501, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 119, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 181, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 99, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise exc.with_traceback(exc.__traceback__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 166, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     teardown.throw(outcome._exception)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/logging.py", line 796, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     return (yield)  # Run all the tests.
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 102, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 351, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 501, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 119, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 181, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 99, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise exc.with_traceback(exc.__traceback__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 166, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     teardown.throw(outcome._exception)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/warnings.py", line 109, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     return (yield)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 166, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     teardown.throw(outcome._exception)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/__init__.py", line 174, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     return (yield)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 87, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     next(wrapper_gen)  # first yield
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/plugin.py", line 263, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     service.start_pytest_item(item)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/service.py", line 123, in wrap
INTERNALERROR>     func(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/service.py", line 713, in start_pytest_item
INTERNALERROR>     self._create_suite_path(test_item)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/service.py", line 123, in wrap
INTERNALERROR>     func(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/service.py", line 462, in _create_suite_path
INTERNALERROR>     path = self._tree_path[item]
INTERNALERROR> KeyError: <Function test_ipsec_domain_address>
```

What's wrong with this, I really dont understand how to tackle this situation

I dont really do much with rp lib just setting up

```
config._inicache["rp_api_key"] = "keymeh
config._inicache["rp_endpoint"] = "url"
config._inicache["rp_project"] = "proj"
config._inicache["rp_launch"] = config.getoption("--run_details")
```

And then i execute pytest --reportportal

So it seems it randomly pops up, this error, only when tests are executed via marked classes (basically lots of tests are collected), if the test is executed individually, its all good, but if the test is within a class that has a mark on it, it seems to through this thing hmm

Also seem to manifest for instances where many tests are executed via -v (path to tests) and there are multiple files with multiple test classes and test methods